# Pyinstaller UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x91 in position 8: invalid start byte

Tags: pyinstaller, pyside6

I have a very easy python code, And I want to package it to be exe file.However, It meet some problem.

There is the code main.py

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

and I use the command

```
pyinstalaler main.py
```

however it comes out

```
>  14358 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from
> 'C:\\python-3.10.9-embed-amd64\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
>     15296 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from
> 'C:\\python-3.10.9-embed-amd64\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
>     15749 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide6.QtCore.py' from 'C:\\python-3.10.9-embed-amd64\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
>     16155 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide6.QtGui.py' from 'C:\\python-3.10.9-embed-amd64\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
>     16640 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.msvc.py' from 'C:\\python-3.10.9-embed-amd64\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "tokenize.py", line 332, in find_cookie
>     UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x91 in position 8: invalid start byte
>     
>     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>     
>         Traceback (most recent call last):
>           File "runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
>           File "runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
>           File "C:\python-3.10.9-embed-amd64\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py",
> line 7, in <module>
>           File "C:\python-3.10.9-embed-amd64\Lib/site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py",
> line 194, in _console_script_run
>             run()
>           File "C:\python-3.10.9-embed-amd64\Lib/site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py",
> line 180, in run
>             run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
>           File "C:\python-3.10.9-embed-amd64\Lib/site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py",
> line 61, in run_build
>             PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
>           File "C:\python-3.10.9-embed-amd64\Lib/site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 971, in main
>             build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
>           File "C:\python-3.10.9-embed-amd64\Lib/site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 893, in build
>             exec(code, spec_namespace)
>           File "C:\Users\Moon\OneDrive\文档\工作\code\python\main.spec", line 7, in <module>
>             a = Analysis(
>           File "C:\python-3.10.9-embed-amd64\Lib/site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 411, in __init__
>             self.__postinit__()
>           File "C:\python-3.10.9-embed-amd64\Lib/site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 173, in __postinit__
>             self.assemble()
>           File "C:\python-3.10.9-embed-amd64\Lib/site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 580, in assemble
>             self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks(self)
>           File "C:\python-3.10.9-embed-amd64\Lib/site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 330, in process_post_graph_hooks
>             module_hook.post_graph(analysis)
>           File "C:\python-3.10.9-embed-amd64\Lib/site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py",
> line 454, in post_graph
>             self._process_hidden_imports()
>           File "C:\python-3.10.9-embed-amd64\Lib/site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py",
> line 510, in _process_hidden_imports
>             self.module_graph.import_hook(import_module_name, caller)
>           File "C:\python-3.10.9-embed-amd64\Lib/site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py",
> line 1518, in import_hook
>             submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
>           File "C:\python-3.10.9-embed-amd64\Lib/site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 429, in _safe_import_module
>             return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
>           File "C:\python-3.10.9-embed-amd64\Lib/site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py",
> line 2053, in _safe_import_module
>             (module, co) = self._load_module(module_name, pathname, loader)
>           File "C:\python-3.10.9-embed-amd64\Lib/site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py",
> line 2143, in _load_module
>             src = loader.get_source(partname)
>           File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in get_source
>           File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 711, in decode_source
>           File "tokenize.py", line 373, in detect_encoding
>           File "tokenize.py", line 337, in find_cookie
```

ps: Windows 10, python 3.10 pyinstaller 5.79.
Try many methods, seems to be encoding problem. mac system can work very ok. However, window cannot work. I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall pyside6 and pyinstaller into a new virtual environment and if that doesn't work you likely need to uninstall and reinstall python

Comment: I try the version of python3.6.5 and works..

Answer (score 0):

correcting error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position

open `\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py`

inside the method `def _load_module`
find:

```py
src = loader.get_source(partname)
```

change to:

```py
try:
    src = loader.get_source(partname)
except: 
    path = loader.get_filename(partname)
    src = loader.get_data(path)
```

ps: I made a pullrequest to the Pyinstaller project which was accepted. So this issue has been resolved.

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/7622